# Does Magneto really need to point his hand while using his powers?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, magneto

Magneto points his hand towards an object in most cases to use his power but in few cases he does without that.

Here are few examples:

**X-Men Apocalypse** ([Youtube Clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFF8_LARxNs))

In factory when he goes back to take revenge he shuts the doors and moves objects without pointing his hand towards them.

**X-Men** ([Youtube Clip](https://youtu.be/qFspH1R3_UE?t=187))

After Magneto kidnaps Rogue and gets confronted by the Professor, he points and fires guns without pointing his hands.

If he can use his powers without pointing his hands then why does he point his hands most of the time?

Comment: Because it looks cool?

Comment: Rule of cool? Aids concentration? Jazz hands? You name it.

Comment: maybe holding his hands in front of him changes the local magnetic field and that concentrate his power? (like Obiwan did when fighting jango fett?)

Comment: Magneto likes to showboat his powers - part of the coming "war on humanity" involves identifying himself and his compatriots as mutants, loud and proud, so to speak.  But Magneto's powers are all mental, so normal people witnessing his power may not associate what's happening with **him** - unless he waves his hands around to make it clear *he's the one who's doing this.*

Comment: @Steve-O That cannot be the reason. In apocalypse he wants to hide himself from others but still points his hand while saving his co-worker in the factory

Comment: Some habits are hard to kick

Comment: Thinking from the point of view of comics, magnetic powers are unlike optic blasts or adamantium claws in that they're invisible.  If Magneto didn't point, it would be hard for the reader to even tell when he was doing something.

Comment: So this is all for viewers/readers to know that he is doing something. No in universe explanation?

Comment: It's also possible, and most likely, that it could be a kind of crutch that helps him focus his intentions. If you're doing something that requires calculating something complex, like odds of XYZ happening after several related events have taken place, plenty of people can do so in their own heads without so much as twitching an eyebrow if necessary. But, those people may also resort to physical movements of some kind, as a crutch like ticking their fingers or talking out loud, to help them keep track of their calculations if the situation allows for it.

Comment: Same basic principal as when you physically rotate the controller to make the car turn more in a racing game. Moving your hands in a lifting motion makes your telepathically-levitated hunk of metal rise higher.

Comment: @Ellesedil I also suspect that but did not find any in universe explanation yet

Comment: Does it have anything to do with two different actors?

Answer (score 1):

I think it reminds him of how he reached out to his family during the Holocaust (thus bending the gates, etc) when they were separated.

Now, he does it so as to never forget what the base, powerless humans had done to him and his family.

Of course, when a battle is most heated, he doesn't always feel the need to do it, he just strives to get the job done to further his cause, especially against Professor X and the X-Men.

Comment: This comes across as opinion rather than an answer.  Suggest you find something to back up your idea, rather than just speculating.

Comment: I like the idea of this answer, do you have any sources which might suggest your point?

Comment: So does he _need_ to do it?

Comment: Tim, you're probably right, it is more opinion than canon; but, many a-time has the weight of opinion affected canon. 

So, being an avid RPG-er, and always thinking about character backstories, it just felt like a plausible idea and one that added a classic dose of prevailing angst that only the expression of "pushing out" (extending forth his hand) versus his childhood "grasping for" his family he was had been separated from, gave Magneto more character...more humanity, even in his despotism.

Comment: Mooz, I'm going by the X-men movies on this point, the intro to X-Men 2.

Comment: SQB, Does Magneto "need" to do it? I think yes, just as much as a dictator needs to ball up and pump his fist when giving a speech, a la Hitler at Nuremberg.